# What is the reasoning that `int.class.cast(null)` works?

Tags: java, casting

I just tried the following:

```
System.out.println(int.class.cast(null));
```

This does exactly what it says in its specification:

> Casts an object to the class or interface represented
>     by this {@code Class} object.
>     @param obj the object to be cast
>     @return the object after casting, or null if obj is null
>     @throws ClassCastException if the object is not
>     null and is not assignable to the type T.

While this seems to be intuitive if the `Class` is some non-primitive class - null is convertible to all classes after all - I wonder why it was decided that for primitive classes such as `int` this doesn't result in a `ClassCastException`. My reasoning would be

```
Foo f = (Foo) null; // Okay
int a = (int) null; // Not okay: "Cannot cast from null to int"
                    // why doesn't Class#cast reflect this?
```

Comment: *This does exactly what it says in its specification* But, why would it not do what it says in the specification?

Comment: I asked because I tried it without reading the specification first, got caught offguard, read it and still find it unsatisfactory. I thought that usage of methods should intuitive by design and maybe I missed a reason off that I can learn something about java

Comment: Fundamentally, *primitive types* are not objects; there are trade-offs to that decision and this is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `int.class` is `Class<Integer>`, so it is equivalent to casting to an `Integer`, cf. [Class Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> The type of `p.class`, where `p` is the name of a primitive type (§4.2), is `Class<B>`, where `B` is the type of an expression of type `p` after boxing conversion (§5.1.7).

Comment: It is just not true that `int.class` should behave the same as `Integer.class` and in fact it doesn't. See `int.class.getField("MIN_VALUE")` vs `Integer.class.getField("MIN_VALUE")`

Comment: @WorldSEnder They don't behave the same but they have the same type.